# MySQLi query fails silently but succedes at SQL shell

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am attempting to pull some data out of my OsTicket installation but for some reason the first SQL query fails silently (Line beginning: `$openTickets`). However the query works when entered into a MySQL shell.

```
<?php
    define('INCLUDE_DIR','dumb hack');
    require_once("./include/ost-config.php");

    $mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Couldn't Connect to MySQL Database.\nError (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . "): " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$openTickets = $mysqli->query("SELECT ticket_id, number, user_id FROM ost_ticket WHERE status='open'");

[...snip...]
?>
```

Comment: if `$openTickets` is returning false, use `$mysqli->error` to figure out what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

See [MySQLI errno](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php)

```
$openTickets = $mysqli->query("SELECT ticket_id, number, user_id FROM ost_ticket WHERE status='open'");
if ($openTickets === false) {
    printf("Errorcode: %d\n", $mysqli->errno);
}
```

Comment: `$mysqli->errno = 0` According to a var dump taken after that line.